# HTML drop down element width not aligning to siblings

Tags: html, css, less

Quite difficult to explain, so I created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Relborg/pen/fGrIE) for you to have a look at. When you hover over a navigation item and the dropdown menu appears. You'll see that some of the items don't line up correctly. I.e. the width of some items are bigger than their sibling items. I just want them all to stretch to the width of the widest list item. (confused yet?) Just have a look at the code pen..

[image]

Comment: If anyone is wondering where my code is, it's at the provided link aka Codepen...

Comment: You should still include your relevant HTML and CSS in the question, your link is not reliable in the long term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `display : inline-block` instead of `float: left` in `/* list item */` css and should add `display : table-row;` into `/* sub list item */` .

```
@dark-blue:               #31394C;
@light-gray:              #E6E6E6;
@gray:                      #B1B2B5;
@dark-gray:               #6D6D6D;
@dark-red:                #d7351b; 
@red:                         #ee2a2e;
@light-red:               #f75d1f;
@dusty-red:               #DE6450;
@light-dusty-red:       #fdc29e;
@dark-dusty-red:        #b50b03;
@sub-nav-red:       #DE5D48;
@white:                     #ffffff;

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rosario);

body {

  background: @dark-blue;

}

#main-navigation {     



  /* initial list */
  ul {

    list-style: none;    

    /* list item */
    li {

      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      background: @dark-red;
      min-width: 105px;
      height: 21px;
      text-align: center;
      margin-right: 10px;           

      /* link */
      a {

        color: @white;
        display: block;
        line-height: 21px;
        text-decoration: none;         
        font-family:        'Rosario', sans-serif;
          font-size:            12px;
        text-transform:     uppercase;

      }

      a:hover {

        color: @white;
        background: @dark-red;

      }           

      /* sub list */
      ul {

        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: -40px;
        display: none;
        border-top: 10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0);
        z-index: 99;


        /* sub list item */
        li {

          background: @sub-nav-red;  
          display : table-row;
          /* sub list link */
          a {

           padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
           white-space: nowrap; 

          }

        }

      }

      ul:hover {
        display: block; 
      }


    }

     li:hover > ul {

        display: block;

     }


  }

}
```

Comment: You are an absolute life saver! Thank you so so much. :-D

Comment: You're welcome. If you think that the answer has solved your problem, you should mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make changes to the below CSS to get them aligned.

**For Instance.**

```
#main-navigation ul li ul li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DE5D48;
    width: 140px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fkpid)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest moving the background, size, and positioning from the `li` to the `ul`, that way the whole list will expand if one item is too big.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give more `min-width`

```
#main-navigation ul li {
float: left;
position: relative;
background: #D7351B;
min-width: 140px;
```

Answer (score 0):

in css, `li` element has: `min-width: 105px;`

change it to `155px` and it will solve it.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple,

You can't use: `top: 100%`

You'll be wanting to update this to be `top: 0` this will align it to the top of its parent.

You may need `top: 11px` in your exact case.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The problem is with the width of each item not matching. Not to do with the gap between parent and child list

Comment: Hi Jamie, I'm not sure if maybe you don't understand my question fully. Did what you suggested and nothing changed...

Comment: @JamieHutber: So why don't you either delete your answer, or edit it to provide an accurate solution.